# APi mocking and redirecting target to localhost api

Tags: api-hacking, api-reversing

Suppose I have got an application which sends request `(GET,POST)` to `google.com:1010/api/req` 
Is it possible to simulate the api on localhost and redirect requests sent to `google.com:1010/api/req` to the mimicked api on localhost, something like `localhost:1010/api/req`?
Are the any tools to facilitate this process?

Comment: Not sure if that's RE even. What OS are you on? There's usually a hosts file where you can specify what name resolves to what IP. Just map google.com to `127.0.0.1` and you're good to go.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik It is Windows 10

Comment: then you can use `c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` to do the job.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik Isn't there any tool available with some additional features for APi Mocking?